# Dynamic primaryKey on ember serializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to set `primaryKey` on ember seializer dynamically. Is it possible?

Here is what I can get from the server as response

```
account: {iban: "ibanValue", currency : "currencyValue"} or {bban: "bbanValue"}
```

Ember code:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

const {
  EmbeddedRecordsMixin,
} = DS;

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  primaryKey: 'iban'
});
```

I setted `iban` as primary key but it can also be `bban`. How can I set one of them as primary key as needed?

Comment: this very much sounds like and [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you a actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: When iban  provided everything works otherwise I am getting :  Error while processing route:  Failed: You must include an 'id' for account-reference in an object passed to 'push'

Comment: ember data expects ids for everything. Ember data base don a very specific data structure. If your not creating this data structure on you server end then I would advise you to not use ember data.

Comment: That said, I'm presuming your objects have ids?

Comment: I am not getting id in the response. I can get iban, bban or pan. One of them

Comment: How do you intend to identify your objects in a `UPDATE` or `DELETE` call?

Answer (score 1):

Ember data is a framework, and all frameworks have their own rules. This one is developed to handle data and so it imposes some structure on your data information. One of these rules is that all the entities (models) must have an `id` property. This actually is a great good practice for all information systems.
That said, you have to decide what you want to use as an `id`, and if for some very strange reasons you have two different properties that could act as `id`, the best way to solve this it to handle it serverside.
In your data add a new `id` property and before returning the data from your  *REST API* you can decide what you want to use as `id` for a specific record and explicitly do it by copying its value to the `id` property.
This way ember data will always have its `id` to work with.

Comment: Thanks guys :)  I fixed the issue by using extractId() method (RESTSerializer)